# Win-Tab not working

Tags: windows-7

I was showing a friend the neat effect of Win-Tab on Windows 7, but when he tried it, it didn't work!  All it does is bring up the Start menu!  What could be causing this?

Comment: Some time ago I installed vista on a laptop with a pretty puny video card - a 64MB ATI - and while aero worked and remained enabled, windows automatically disabled some of the more resource intensive effects, including flip3d.  I recall a message being shown shortly after I installed the OS indicating that the graphics card was a "highly contentious resource", and some effects were being disabled as a result (or something to that effect).  Unfortunately I do not know how to check whether or not this aero is in this degraded state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check that **Desktop Composition** (i.e. Aero) is enabled:

```
Control Panel -> System and Maintenance -> System
Advanced system settings
Advanced tab
Performance -> Settings
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Does he have Aero enabled?

<kbd>Windows Flag</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> does not work when Aero is disabled.

I think due to this, it does not work on Vista Home Basic or Windows 7 starter either.

Comment: If your tweaking custom settings, I found I had to apply new settings then toggle "desktop compostion off/on" to get WIN + TAB  to work again. (Historical note, and tested on Vista Business SP2)

Answer (score 1):

Is your friend holding down <kbd>Win</kbd> when hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd>?

Even on my XP work machine, holding <kbd>Win</kbd> and pressing any other key doesn't pop up the Start menu; the start menu only pops up if you press <kbd>Win</kbd> and then release it without pressing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse over something in the taskbar. If no image appears above it, either Aero is disabled or — as stated earlier — you have Vista Home Basic. You can confirm this by right-clicking on computer and selecting properties. Aero Glass isn't available in this version of Vista.