# How open all windows which are belong to one application?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/428815/shortcut-key-to-display-all-windows-7-windows) is how show all opened windows. Is there a way to do so but only for one application? For example click on `chrome` and open show all chrome windows.

OS is windows-10

Comment: At least you can see most of them in the task bar if you hover over the icon.

Comment: It display preview only, not open windows.