# How to make window button + tab button working in window7 home basic?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I tried a shortcut effect by `Winkey+Tab` on one of my computers and it worked, but when I tried the same combination on my laptop it didn't work.

I searched it on Google and followed the instructions as given in this link: [Winkey+Tab Not Working](https://superuser.com/questions/83587/win-tab-not-working)

But when I checked the checkbox **"Enable desktop composition"**, it unchecks itself when I click on apply or OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it because Windows Aero isn't natively supported in the Home Basic version of window. Although, there are several 3rd party applications that will achieve the effect for you.

I would suggest doing a search for "aero on windows 7 home basic"